# How to interpret Allan Variance curves that do not follow the canonical shape

Tags: time-series, noise, white-noise

I am currently working on characterizing the noise sources of a Global Navigation Satellite System (GNSS) sensor using an Allan Variance plot, which is commonly employed to analyze frequency stability in atomic clocks, but has since been extended to other applications such as Inertial Measurement Units (IMUs) and sensors.

A typical (modified) Allan Deviation plot exhibits a distinctive "bowl" shape where different noise contributors are distinctly represented (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Allan_variance) and [Example](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/61/5_regimes_of_modified_Allan_variance_as_a_function_of_averaging_time.png)).

In order to characterize the diverse noise sources affecting each component of the GNSS sensor, I collected data at a fixed location for five consecutive days with samples recorded every 0.05 seconds (20 Hz), under two separate configurations:

```
-Antenna facing upward
-Antenna facing sideways
```

Below is an extract from the obtained data:
[image: GNSS Solution over time]

Assuming precise knowledge of the receiver's position, I computed the errors and plotted their respective Allan deviations for both configurations, depicted as follows:

For the antenna facing up, I get the following Allan curve:
[image: allan curve antenna facing up]

For the antenna facing sideways, I get the following curve:
[image]

As observed, these Allan deviations hint towards a dominant presence of random walk noise, which contradicts expectations of boundedness. Specifically, I expect a GNSS estimate to fluctuate around the true value, due to factors like atmospheric conditions, satellite constellation geometry, clock biases, etc.

Thus, the assumption about noise interpretation must be incorrect as random walk is by definition unbounded. I would appreciate suggestions for accurately interpreting these results.

Additionally, I provide Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) representations of the errors, organized identically as before:
[image: FFT antenna facing up]
[image: FFT antenna facing sideways]

These FFT outputs seem consistent with the random walk conjecture when compared against canonical noises examples (see [this document](https://research.reading.ac.uk/fiduceo/wp-content/uploads/sites/129/2020/12/noise_and_allan_variance_report.pdf), top of page 6 for an example of different noises FFT).

My analysis of the noise in the signal based on the Allan variance curves is therefore wrong. Would you have a suggestion for reading these curves correctly?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.